# Rails - activeadmin, duplicating has_many records upon updating "parent" record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

My models are as follows:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_images
end

class ProjectImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Here's the activeadmin file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
  remove_filter :projects_sectors
  permit_params :title, :info, :case_study, project_images_attributes: [:image, :cover]

  index do
    column :title
    actions
  end

  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
    f.inputs "Project" do
    f.input :title
    f.input :info
    f.input :case_study, :as => :file
  end

  f.inputs "Images" do
    f.has_many :project_images, :allow_destroy => true, :heading => false, :new_record => true do |img_f|
      img_f.input :image, :as => :file , :hint => f.template.image_tag(img_f.object.image)
      img_f.input :cover
    end
  end
  f.actions
end


end
```

The problem is that when i simply edit a project and click on update project, it simply duplicates all the records that exist for relationship at that point. Eg. if i have 2 images under 1 project, after changing say, the project title, i will end up with 4 images.

Hope it's clear what the issue is. Would appreciate greatly if anybody could give me a litle help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to permit the id of the images: `project_images_attributes: [:id, :image, :cover]`

If you don't permit the id, it will be null in the action, and rails thinks it's a new record and save it.

Comment: I haven't had time to test this yet. But it makes total sense. So u get the bounty :)

Comment: Thanks. :D I had the same issue and this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same problem as [this one](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-keep-%28not-replace%29-files-on-nested-edits) discussed on the CarrierWave wiki. Instead of generating input fields for existing images, generate an image tag and a 'remove?' option. If you generate an input field for them, then you'll end up with duplicate results.

Comment: I'm not sure, cuz it doesnt replace the files. It duplicates the amount of records for project_images currently on for the project instance.

Answer (score -1):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
  controller do
    def apply_filtering(chain)
      super(chain).distinct
    end
  end

  # your code
end
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful when they also include an explanation.