# Active Admin and instantiating a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activeadmin

I have two tables: Event and Image

```
Events:
id
name
date
location


Images:
id
file
caption
event_id
```

An Event has many images and an Image belongs to an Event.

My ultimate goal is to upload multiple images at once in Active Admin. I have read several other posts suggesting I do the following:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

  mount_uploader :file, AvatarUploader
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event

  mount_uploader :file, AvatarUploader
end
```

Then, in my admin/event.rb, I have the following:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Event Details" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :location
    f.input :date

  f.has_many :images do |p|
    p.input :file, :as => :file, :for => [Image.new]
  end

end

f.actions
```

I am able to visually get multiple image upload fields, the problem is that when I save, the images actually aren't saving. I believe this is because I am not creating a new image (Image.new) on each file upload. Is there a way to do this in active admin?

Thanks

Comment: Did you permit the params properly?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234859/rails-activeadmin-duplicating-has-many-records-upon-updating-parent-record/24321721#24321721

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. Had no idea I had to include the :id. For some reason, I can't upvote? If you want to really quickly make it an answer, I will accept (since it is correct!)

Comment: It's enough for me if you upvote the answer that I linked. :)

Comment: This is super odd. It let me upvote your previous comment but not the first one? Sorry, this never happened before. The upvote on your last comment really applies to the first one! Thanks again